# Convert IQueryable generic to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor, json.net

I'm producing a projection via:

```
var query = from book in books
    select new
    {
        label = book.Title,
        value = book.ID
    };
```

In my razor page I need to use:

```
    var booksArray = [{
        @(json)
    }];
```

such that the resulting array looks like:

```
label: 'c++',
value: 'c++'
}, {
label: 'java',
value: 'java'
}, {
label: 'php',
value: 'php'
}, {
label: 'coldfusion',
value: 'coldfusion'
}
```

I've come very very close from a couple different approaches - I can get a string that looks correct on the server side but when rendered to the page itself, all the `'` marks become `&#39;` .

But focusing on achieving this via JSON.net...

The most likely approach seems like it should be:

```
var json = JsonConvert.ToString(query);
```

but that tosses:

```
Unsupported type: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Project.Entity.Book,<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Int32]]. Use the JsonSerializer class to get the object's JSON representation.
```

What's the correct JSON.net syntax?

thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a combination of [.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) and [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

`ToArray()` to evaluate the query and make `JsonConvert` happy

```
var query = from book in books
    select new
    {
        label = book.Title,
        value = book.ID
    };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToArray());
```

Note: you need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` if you want to serialize complex types. `JsonConvert.ToString` is used to convert simple types like bool, guid, int, uri etc.

And in your view `Html.Raw` to not html encode the JSON:

```
var booksArray = @(Html.Raw(json))
```

Comment: Hitting a runtime error on the 'var json' line. Unsupported type: <>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.String][]. I've made an explicit 'ToString()' conversion for both elements (ID is actually an integer) but no change to the reported error. mny thx

Comment: That's a good answer... But at this time I have serious issues with performance using that function